# In Mercurial (Hg), what is a good way to list all files modified by me since revision 4822?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

I may do development work for 2 weeks before one or two features get pushed to all the production servers, and since this is a Ruby on Rails project, many files can be modified.

So using Mercurial as the source control, is there a good way to list all filenames that are modified (or added) by me, between the current version and revision 4822?  (the number 4822 is before I do the first `hg push`, I do an `hg out` and see that the changeset that will go out is 4823, so I will diff with 4822)

**(Update: This is to list files only modified by me, as opposed to the other 38 files modified by my teammates)**

Better yet, is there a good way to invoke `hg vdiff` automatically, so when invoked as

```
checkdiff Peter 4822
```

It will do

```
hg vdiff -r 4822 [... the list of filenames modified by Peter (or me) since 4822]
```

Comment: You can do an `hg vdiff` automatically with the `alias` command.

Comment: What about the option `-u` (`--user`) in `hg log`?

Comment: @Sanata and then use `--style` and a style file to show filenames only, and use `| sort | uniq` ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `hg log` and some nice one-liner?

`hg log --user Peter --verbose | grep files | sed -e 's/files://' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq` will give all files modified by you since beginning of repository. Use `--rev` to limit revision scope.