# How to get list of files that were affected since a specific revision in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

How do I get a list of all files affected in a changeset since rev 3456?

**Note:**
I tried `hg log --rev 3456:tip --template "{files}"\n` but there are several problems

1. If a changeset affects multiple files, they all appear on the same line.
2. This also shows the same file multiple times if a file was involved in many changsets.

Comment: 3 sounds like a bug.  do you have an exmaple where a merge changes a file from the first parent but does not show up in hg log?

Comment: @John: it's not a bug. I misunderstood something about merge changesets. I've remove problem 3 from the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a list of which files changed between hg versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024510/generating-a-list-of-which-files-changed-between-hg-versions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hg stat --rev 3456`

`hg stat --rev 3456:tip` to exclude uncommitted changes

Comment: In my repo, changeset 3456 is the tip. Tortoise hg shows 3 files for changeset 3456 but `"hg stat --rev 3456"` does not show any files. That changeset is a merge.

Comment: Huh?  If 3456 is the tip (tip means most recent changeset added to the repo) then how do you want "all files affected in a changeset since rev 3456"?  To get the list of all changes @robert is suggesting you need to --rev options or one with a colon.

Answer (score 1):

create a file named "mystyle"

```
changeset = "{files}"
file="{file}\n"
```

Then `hg log --style mystyle --rev 3456:tip | sort | unique`

Comment: the format is good with your example but I have just realized that `hg -log` does not give me what I need. I have updated my question. See problem 3 in my question.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400921/in-mercurial-hg-what-is-a-good-way-to-list-all-files-modified-by-me-since-revi) that covers the same issue, with the added restriction that the search be restricted to files belonging to 'myself.'  You can simply remove the '--user' and it should do what you need.